# ebay "errorId": 1100, "longMessage": "Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request."

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, postman, ebay-api

I managed to set up a developer account to get API responses working on the API explorer. However, I'm trying to connect to Postman and have been getting the following error messages.

I have gotten my user access token as follows:

[image]

- The Callback URL:  I have used the RuName (eBay Redirect URL name)
- Auth URL: I have used `https://auth.sandbox.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize` (https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-consent-request.html#configure)
- Access Token URL: I have used the `https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token` (https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html)
  ClientID and Client Password I've used the credentials from my developer account

This returns the following token:

[image]

As you can see a `USER ACCESS TOKEN`.

When I go to use the request in an API put request I always get the following error:

[image]

The token seems to be right.

I try the same call in the built in API explorer and it works.

Please could someone advise its driving me crazy, probably something I've done wrong but any ideas?

During Authentication the following happens it prompts me to login and then shares the oath code (it doesn't tell me to accept the application as stated in document not sure why though)

Comment: during authorization flow i believe you are asked to specify a scope, it's possible you didn't grant yourself permission to make the call you are trying to make.

Comment: Hey I wasn't prompted to grant myself permission in the authorization flow, when I click get new access token it just tells me to login and then shares the auth token (I've attached the screenshots to the original question if that helps)

Comment: From your link here https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-consent-request.html#configure one of the parameters is "scope" (you can see it in the table on that page). You should add the full requests you have sent to the question.

Comment: you are right that was the error thanks a million

Comment: no problemo, glad you got it working

Comment: I've provided the scope in the URL, but where does the token get returned?